# How to get a product variant by SKU and get parent product details as well?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I need to get a product variant as an object in Twig, as well as get its parents details (the product fields, not just the variant fields). My first guess starts with this:

```
{% set variant = craft.commerce.products.sku('my-sku-number') %}
```

But that doesn't work. I've also tried adding a the `.first()` limiter to the end. What am I missing?

**Edit**

Thoughts... should I be trying a search/find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({
  hasVariant: {sku: 'my-sku-number'}
}).first() %}
```

See: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-products#hasvariant

If you only want to search the default variant of the product:

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products({defaultSku : 'my-sku-number'}).first() %}
```

See: https://craftcommerce.com/docs/craft-commerce-products#defaultsku

Comment: Thanks Luke, that works. Turns out the client entered some skus to search with a related product, before adding those specific products and skus. Nothing like deadlines between developers and marketers!